# How to access props data from different screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

New to React Native and trying to figure out the right way to access props from another screen.
Most of the answers I found online were all very different, so I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to do it.

**App.js** - Here `user` is the currently connected user's data.

```
{ user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (...)
}
```

On other screens, I'm sending the user to `HomeScreen` this way:

```
navigation.navigate('Home', {user: user})
```

**HomeScreen.js** - In this function, I want to access the user's data from **App.js**, or any other screen that `sends` the user.

```
export default function HomeScreen(props, {navigation}) {...}
```

How should I structure my code in *HomeScreen.js* to receive the user correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Context API, documentation about that can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Here's an example usage:

Create a provider for the user details

```js
// Import createContext from react
import {createContext} from 'react'

// Create a context that holds a user and a function to change the user details
export const UserContext = createContext({user: null, setUser: (user) => {}})
```

Wrap the main navigator that contains your home screen with the provider from `UserContext`

```js
function MainNavigator() {
  // For state management, useState for the user
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  return (
    // Pass the user and setUser inside the Provider value for consumption
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
      <YourNavigator>
        { /* Your screen */ }
        <Stack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </YourNavigator>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Consume the context inside your `HomeScreen` component using a simple hook

```js
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../where/your/provider/is'

export default function HomeScreen(props) {
  // Consume the context!
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext)

  return <>{ /* Your screen layout */}</>
}
```

This is just a simple example for this particular use case, I suggest learning more about Context API and play around with it

Hope you find this helpful